# Printing out the data structure for a Google Realtime Document

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I'm experimenting with building an app using the Google Realtime API and I want to be able to print out a dump of the data in the document for debugging purposes. Is there anything out there that makes this easy? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the export capability to get a json dump of the document.  See https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/realtime/get